# When is a Module category monoidal?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a monoidal category and $M$ a left module category over $\mathcal{C}$. That is, a category equipped with an exact bifunctor $F:\mathcal{C}\otimes M\rightarrow M$ satisfying some conditions (see Ostrik's paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139 for a nice exposition). My question is: What conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ ensure that $M$ is monoidal?

Comment: Decategorification of your question would be to ask what conditions on a ring $R$ ensure that an $R$-module $M$ is a ring. The answer would be - no conditions would ensure this. The same I believe happens with your question - it is an additional structure on $M$ which might or might not exist and might or might not be unique, no matter what conditions does $\mathcal C$ satisfy.

Comment: Perhaps the question means to unpack the monoidal structure in terms of more primitive structures on $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ostrik's paper shows that every indecomposable module category comes from a connected algebra $A$ given by the internal action endomorphisms. If  $A$ can be chosen to be commutative in the center $Z(\mathcal C$), then the module category has the structure of a monoidal category, see e.g. here http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0569 and references therein.

If $\mathcal C$ is braided it is enough to ask to ask $A$ to be commutative in $\mathcal C$. There are actually two possible ways to do this.

Comment: Just as @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე pointed out must happen, this answer does not literally answer the question: it does not give conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ alone that makes $M$ monoidal --it instead gives on conditions on $M$.

Comment: Yes I overlooked this. But take SU(2) level 10 then there is a two module categories which are tensor categories and one which is not. One condition would be that the category is symmetric